# AD inactive user with OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'd like to get a list of users that haven't used their account in the past 90 days. And I'd like to see in which OU/DC they are without getting the CN. is this possible? I'm using PowerShell ISE for this

I currently have

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly –AccountInActive –TimeSpan 90:00:00:00 
                 –ResultPageSize 2000 –ResultSetSize $null 
      | ?{$_.Enabled –eq $True} 
      | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, LastLogonDate  
      | Export-CSV “C:\Temp\InActiveUsers.CSV” –NoTypeInformation
```

This returns the full distinguished name and I have to remove the CN in Excel afterwards, which is an annoying mess - I'd rather not deal with that repeatedly.

The solution doesn't have to be based on `search-adaccount`, but I do want it to be in a single code, so I don't have to get a list of users and then use that list with another bit of code to get their OU/DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the superior DN by splitting the string on the first non-escaped comma and discard the CN part:

```
# ...
| Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,@{Name='OU';Expression={($_.DistinguishedName -split '(?<!\\),',2)[1]}}, LastLogonDate
```

Comment: I just tried this and it it seemed to work for most entries. but there are some that have 2 CNs. is there a way to get rid of the second one if there is one?

Comment: @RamsesBeauBams I don't think you'd want that - `CN` is also the RDN for _containers_ (such as the built-in "Users" container)

Answer (score 1):

If your domain is running at least Windows 2012, you can ask for the [`msDS-parentdistname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/85d11f99-0988-4996-97fb-bfa95e0159b2) attribute, which will give you the DN of the parent object. It's a constructed attribute, which means it's calculated at the time you ask for it. You have to specifically ask for it, which means in this case I think you'll have to pipe the result into `Get-ADUser` to do so. That might slow things down quite a bit (there are faster ways to do this) but it should work.

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly –AccountInActive –TimeSpan 90:00:00:00 
                 –ResultPageSize 2000 –ResultSetSize $null 
      | ?{$_.Enabled –eq $True}
      | Get-AdUser -Properties Name, SamAccountName, "msDS-parentdistname", LastLogonDate
      | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, "msDS-parentdistname", LastLogonDate
      | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\InActiveUsers.CSV" –NoTypeInformation
```